# How to pass values to the command class from codebehind class in sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore

Recently I added a button on sitecore content editor so the user can click on the button for a particualr operations.

When the user clicks on the button, aspx page is loaded as a popup winodw. There is button on the aspx page as well.

What I would like to do is to pass some values to the run method in the class inherted from Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command from the aspx code behind button click event.

The codes are as below:

```
      //command class

   public class DummyTickets : Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Overridable method from base class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">command to be executed.</param>
    public override void Execute(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context)
    {
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", context.Parameters);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The web form pops up in a new window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"> pipeline args </param>
    protected static void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (!args.IsPostBack)
        {
            var urlString = new UrlString(@"/sitecore modules/Shell/RSL/Dummy Tickets      Generator/Dummytickets.aspx");
            SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlString.ToString(), "900", "800", string.Empty, false);
            args.WaitForPostBack(true);
        }
        else
        {
            //get some values from codehind.....
            if (args.HasResult)
            {
                if (Sitecore.Context.Item.Name == "Content Editor")
                {
                    Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


    //code behind
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.ddlDraws.DataSource = this.GetCurrentDraws();
            this.ddlDraws.DataTextField = "Title";
            this.ddlDraws.DataValueField = "ArtUnionID";
            this.ddlDraws.DataBind();
            this.ddlDraws.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select draw---", "0")); 
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void btnDummyTickets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //how to pass values to the command class when the user clicks the button.
        SheerResponse.SetDialogValue("testing");
    }
```

Please let me know the right approach for this. Is this achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can not pass arguments to Run method when we use an user interface (aspx page), instead handle required code on postback button of aspx page. Please refer to my blog for a complete example http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.co.nz/2014/09/example-of-sitecore-command-template_21.html. In case you need to handle a post back in custom command, please use JavaScript popup window http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.co.nz/2014/09/example-of-sitecore-command-template.html